# How to use document.getElementById("table-name").rows.length; inside a Firefox Addon SDK extension

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, firefox-addon

I'm trying to create a simple Firefox extension for duolingo.com so that I can see the total number of words that I have completed for a language. The list of words that a person completes are displayed on https://www.duolingo.com/words. The words are inside a HTML table with the class name 'vocab-list'. Each row in that table contains a new word. So I'm trying to get a count of all the rows in that table.

I have looked at some tutorials for creating Firefox extensions but I'm not able to understand exactly how JavaScript code can be used to manipulate the DOM. I want to do something like this inside the index.js but it's not working:

```
var buttons = require('sdk/ui/button/action');
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
const {Cc, Ci} = require("chrome");
var prompts = Cc["@mozilla.org/embedcomp/prompt-service;1"].getService(Ci.nsIPromptService);
var button = buttons.ActionButton({
  id: "mozilla-link",
  label: "Visit Mozilla",
  icon: {
    "16": "./icon-16.png",
    "32": "./icon-32.png",
    "64": "./icon-64.png"
  },
  onClick: handleClick
});

function handleClick(state) {
tabs.open("https://www.duolingo.com/words");
var wordCount = document.getElementById("vocab-list").rows.length;
var msg = "Total number of words completed:" + wordCount;
prompts.alert(null, "Duolingo Word Counter Extension", msg); 
}
```

This is the error that I get:

```
JPM [info] Starting jpm run on Duolingo Word Counter
JPM [info] Creating a new profile
console.error: duolingo-addon:
JPM [error]   Message: ReferenceError: document is not defined
  Stack:
    handleClick@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/toolkit/loader.js -> resource://duolingo-addon/index.js:36:5
```

I'm not able to understand why I can't use JavaScript directly and why does it have to be defined inside a variable. Thanks for any help.

**UPDATE - HERE IS THE UPDATED CODE BASED ON THE COMMENTS**

```
    var buttons = require('sdk/ui/button/action');
    var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
    var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
    var data = require("sdk/self").data;
    var button = buttons.ActionButton({
      id: "mozilla-link",
      label: "Visit Mozilla",
      icon: {
        "16": "./icon-16.png",
        "32": "./icon-32.png",
        "64": "./icon-64.png"
      },
      onClick: handleClick
    });

function handleClick(state) {
        pageMod.PageMod({
        include: "*.duolingo.com",
        contentScriptFile: data.url("myScript.js"),
        contentScriptWhen: "ready",
        attachTo: ["existing", "top"]
        });
}
```

And the myScript.js file:

```
var wordCount = document.getElementById("word-count").innerHTML; 
window.alert("Total number of words completed: " + wordCount);
```

When I click on the firefox tab now, the code runs and shows a popup displaying the total word count.

Answer (score 2):

The `handleClick` function is running within the extension's background page, it is not injected into duolingo. You need to use `pageMod`:

```
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");

pageMod.PageMod({
    include: "*.duolingo.com",
    contentScriptFile: [
        data.url("myscript.js")
    ],
    contentScriptWhen: "ready",
    attachTo: ["existing", "top"]
});
```

`myscript.js` would contain any code that would be injected into and operate upon the DOM itself.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I used part of your code and now I have something that kind of does what I wanted to do. I've updated my original post to show that.

Comment: @user3530588 note that registering a page-mod is slightly less effective than running the script only in the tabs you open.

Answer (score 1):

Because the browsers run separate OS processes for the main browser/add-on code and for the web-page, there are [two types of scripts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Two_Types_of_Scripts) - add-on and content scripts.

To have your code running in the context of a page, you have to use `tab.attach()` in your case (there are other [APIs available](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts) for other scenarios). From the [Open a web page tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Open_a_Web_Page):

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");
tabs.open({
  url: "http://www.example.com",
  onReady: runScript
});

function runScript(tab) {
  tab.attach({
    contentScript: "document.body.style.border = '5px solid red';"
  });
}
```

You can use other options of [tab.attach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/tabs#attach(options)) to control the content script, for example use `contentScriptFile` to point to a separate file instead of defining the content script as a string.

Comment: Thanks for your response. There's a lot of useful info in it.